# Erase MacDrive OS X partition without disrupting Windows partition?

Tags: hfs+

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) installation.  A while after I installed it, I reserved some space for OS X and created a partition for it.  I use MacDrive to access the data on the OS X partition from Windows.  I no longer have need of the OS X partition and would like to remove the partition, but MacDrive warns me that I will lose ALL my data if I remove the partition.

How can I reclaim that partition without disrupting my Windows installation?

Comment: Please clarify - your question title and last sentence ask two different things (*without disrupting Windows* vs. *without disrupting OS X*). Though based on the rest of the question I assume you meant *without disrupting the Windows partition*.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.